# How to manage URL rewrites with a GCP load balancer?

Tags: rewrite, google-cloud-platform

We have a single-page web application deployed on a GCP bucket with a load balancer in front of it.
All URLs such as `example.com/login` should be rewritten as `example.com/#/login`. Without being rewritten the default behaviour is to go fetch some `login.html` but we only have and need `index.html`, the application handles the routing.

How to configure the load-balancer to achieve such a task?

Comment: Redirection on LB level is currently not possible on GCP. You may refer to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733) where some of the users have recommendations on how to redirect within the app. If this doesn’t help, you may file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1010239) with the load balancing component using the [Google issue-tracking tool](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Answer (score 4):

Google LB is capable of:

- URL redirect
- URL rewrite

based on **URL prefixes** since the summer 2020: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management

Official blog announcement: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/how-to-use-new-traffic-control-features-in-cloud-load-balancing

Seems LB is primitive rewrite engine (only prefixes, no regex) so you cannot run SPA apps with LB, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648022/deploy-spa-application-on-google-cloud-storage-using-load-balancer-and-cdn

**UPDATE 2023** Actually it is possible to create SPA apps with GCP offer utilizing Bucket default 404 handler to `index.html`. See link above.

**UPDATE2 2023** Google LB got capability to match against wildcard `*` (including recursive `**`): https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#wildcards-regx-dynamic-route

Comment: That actually saved my life. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Redirection on LB level is currently not possible on GCP. You may refer to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733) where some of the users have recommendations on how to redirect within the app. If this doesn’t help, you may file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1010239) with the load balancing component using the [Google issue-tracking tool](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).